# Tomcat in Intellij Idea Community Edition

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

Is it possible to run a web application using Tomcat Server in Intellij Idea Community Edition?

I tried to find some information about it but haven't achived any success.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are using maven, you can use this command `mvn tomcat:run`, but first you add in your pom.xml this structure into build tag, just like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>mvn-webapp-test</finalName>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I don't see "Application Server" option at File->Settings in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 version. How can that be made enabled.

Comment: And what if you don't use Maven?

Comment: will this config also support debugging?

Comment: @iarielduarte in tag <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version> I have a issue. This  maven.compiler.plugin.version in red color, what I have to do?

Comment: @Bhavesh Did you achieve to use tomchat  in Intellij Idea Community Edition?

Comment: @Elaman Aitymbet If you are using Java8, this may be the setup you need: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Yes, this also support debugging, just start configuration with using debug button instead of run.

Comment: Can also create a maven configuration and use this command in the "Run" text box:   tomcat:run

Answer (score 68):

Intellij Community does not offer Java application server integration. Your alternatives are

1. buying Intellij licence,
2. switching to Eclipse ;)
3. installing *Smart Tomcat* plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9492, make [following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Wcp.png) (image)
4. installing *IDEA Jetty Runner* plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7505
5. running the application server from Maven, Gradle, whatever, as outlined in the other answers.

I personally installed the Jetty Runner plugin (Jetty is fine for me, I do not need Tomcat) and I am satisfied with this solution. I had to deal with [IntelliJ idea - Jetty, report an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570378/intellij-idea-jetty-report-an-exception), though.

Comment: Smart Tomcat plugin is handy as well.

Comment: Thanks, Smart Tomcat is better with multi-module maven projects.

Comment: I tried to set up a project in Intellij that use Jetty Runner, but have not succeeded yet, I always met HTTP ERROR 404 whatever url I tried, I doubt Jetty Runner plugin is working or not. I also tried the Readme with the Jetty Runner GitHub page's instrution, still no luch. Do you have a project that can share with me that is working?

Comment: SmartTomcat does not let access to tomcat server, we can only access deployed war url. This is problematic if deployed instance needs to communicate with other services(other war's microservices - diff project) running on same tomcat. Finally, Option 2 worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Using Maven, try `tomcat7-maven-plugin`:

```
  <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <path>/</path>
                      <contextFile>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/app-config.xml</contextFile>
                      <mode>context</mode>
                      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                      <warDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warDirectory>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
  </build>
```

Run it using `tomcat7:run-war`

More goals [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Comment: I use "tomcat:run-war -DskipTests" goal and http://localhost:8080/main address line, where main is my artifactId. But don't know about `web.xml`, It says: [WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true').

Comment: I'm wondering why it works ONLY if you remove <pluginManagment> tag which covers <plugins> tag.

Comment: pluginManagment says what plugin version to use, but doesn't execute the plugins.

Answer (score 7):

Tomcat (Headless) can be integrated with IntelliJ Idea - Community edition.

Step-by-step instructions are as below:

1. Add `tomcatX-maven-plugin` to pom.xml

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>SampleProject</path>
                </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Add new run configuration as below:

   ```
   Run >> Edit Configurations >> + >> Maven

   Parameters tab ...
   Name :: Tomcat
   Working Directory :: Project Root Directory
   Command Line :: tomcat7:run

   Runner tab ...
   VM Options :: <user needed options>
   JRE :: <project needed>
   ```
3. Invoke Tomcat in Run/Debug mode directly from IntelliJ  Run >> Run/Debug menu

**NOTE**: Though this is considered a hacking of using using Tomcat integration features of IntelliJ - Enterprise version features, but I would consider this a programmatic way integrating tomcat to the IntelliJ Idea - community edition.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use maven plugin, or simple java program. No need for IDE plugin.
See for example Main class from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

Comment: + Pretty useful link.

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat can also be integrated with IntelliJ Idea - Community Edition with Tomcat Runner Plugin.

Details below:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8266-tomcat-runner-plugin-for-intellij

Comment: How do you deploy the war?

Answer (score 2):

**Using *Tomcat 9* in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition without installing any plugin**

*Note: Make sure environment variables **JAVA_HOME** and **CATALINA_HOME** is set. And in case value for **JAVA_HOME** or **CATALINA_HOME** is reset recently then restart IntelliJ IDEA before proceeding further.*

1. First open the project in IntelliJ IDEA and then click on `File` > `Settings...` > `Tools` > `External Tools`, then click on the **+** button.
2. Then we have to specify the **Name** for the *Tomcat*, then in the **Program** we
   have to specify the path for the **catalina.bat** file in the **bin** folder in
   the folder where *Tomcat* is installed, then in **Arguments** we have to write `jpda run` and then click on **Ok** and then on **Apply**.
3. After that we can we run the *Tomcat* by clicking on `Tools` > `External Tools` > `name_you_provided_for_tomcat`.

Then we have to put the necessary files of the application we want to host on the *Tomcat* in the **webapps** folder in the folder where *Tomcat* is installed.

Answer (score 1):

The maven plugin and embedded Tomcat are usable work-arounds (I like second better because you can debug) but actual web server integration is a feature only available in intelij paid editions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible and its fairly easy.

1. Near the run button, from the dropdown, choose "edit configurations..."
2. On the left, click the plus, then maven and rename it "Tomcat" on the right side.
3. for command line, enter "spring-boot:run"
4. Under the runner tab, for 'VM Options', enter "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms128m -Xmx512m
   -Djava.awt.headless=true"  NOTE: 'use project settings' should be unticked.
5. For environment variables enter "env=dev"
6. Finally, click Ok.

When you're ready to press run, if you go to "localhost:8080/< page_name > " you'll see your page.

My pom.xml file is the same as the Official spring tutorial
[Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: He ask for running JavaEE application not Spring Boot app particularly.

Comment: Works like a charm for a Spring boot application though. No need to install any tomcat plugins with this approach. In fact, none of the tomcat plugins mentioned in other answers worked for me for a spring boot app.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is already answered, however what I am writing here is just my observation so other fellows in the community can save some of their time.
I tried running a spring-mvc project using the embedded tom-cat in Intellij communit edition.

First try I did was using the Gradle tom-cat plugin, however the problem that I faced there is the tomcat server just starts once, after that from the second start the build complains saying that a container is already running.
There are so many open thread on the web about this, for some it works and for most of the people (almost 90% of the web threads that I broke my head with, faced the same problem of container not getting started the second time. The resolution is not there.

After wasting a lot lot of my time, I finally decided to switch to maven tom-cat plugin and do the same spring-mvc setup with maven that I did with gradle and VOILA! it worked in the first short.

So long story short, if you are setting up spring-mvc project in intellij community edition, please consider maven tomcat plugin.

Hope this helps somebody's hours of exploration across various web forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tomcat plugin with gradle. For more information, you [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin).

```
apply plugin: 'tomcat'

dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.2.4'
}

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopPort = 8090
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stfu'
tomcatRunWar.contextPath = "/$rootProject.name"
tomcatRunWar.ajpPort = 8000

if (checkBeforeRun.toBoolean()) {
    tomcatRunWar { dependsOn += ['check'] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used  Jay Lin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086974/4759176). Highly recommend it.

If you **never used Maven before** and **don't want** to go deep into it: follow Jay Lin's answer, but also do this:

1. right click on your project name -> Add Framework support -> Maven.
2. Then install maven from here http://maven.apache.org/install.html. Do what it says, run the commands.
3. Then install spring-boot from here https://mvnrepository.com.
4. Then follow the error messages if there are any - maybe you would need to install some other stuff (just google it and that mvnrepository.com would come up). To install use this command:

   `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=path`

replace `path` with where you downloaded the `jar` file, replace version, group and artifact id with info from mvnrepository.com.

6. Further errors I encountered:

I had to create a class in src/main/java (with simple `System.out.println` command in main) and add `<start-class>main.java.Hello</start-class>` in `<properties>` tag in `pom.xml`. Btw, the `pom.xml` should appear itself when you do the first action from my answer - copy paste Jay Lin's code there.

Another error I got was connected to `JAVA_HOME` variable and the verion stuff. Somewhy it thought jdk is 7th version and I was telling it was 8th. So I changed the java version tag in `<properties>` to this `<java.version>1.7</java.version>`.

Now it works fine! Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle, you can try my script: https://github.com/Adrninistrator/IDEA-IC-Tomcat .This script will build files for web application, create a Tomcat instance, start Tomcat and load the web application.

Comment: You script doesn't have README file. Please update your script to help others how to start with it.

Comment: Thank you. I add a README.md and a runTomcat-en.gradle script which output English.

Answer (score 0):

I think maven is not installed properly. check with `mvn --v`

or

Please check maven home path in env variables
or you have created this project before the installation of maven

Answer (score 0):

[Polaris Tomcat Server](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22429-polaris-tomcat-server) plugin is available in Intellij Idea Community Edition. It is very similar to the tomcat plugin in Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Please demonstrate how using that will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am using intellij CE to create the WAR, and deploying the war externally using tomcat deployment manager. This works for testing the application however I still couldnt find the way to debug it.

1. open cmd and current dir to tomcat/bin.
2. you can start and stop the server using the batch files start.bat and shutdown.bat.
3. Now build your app using mvn goal in intellij.
4. Open localhost:8080/  **Your port number may differ.
5. Use this tomcat application to deploy the application, If you get the authentication error, you would need to set the credentials under conf/tomcat-users.xml.

Answer (score -2):

For Intellij 14.0.0 the Application server option is available under 
View > Tools window > Application Server (But if it is enable, i mean if you have any plugin installed)

Comment: What server plugins can we install in the ce version?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-application-server-integration-plugins.html I dont think that appservers are enabled in CE version

Answer (score -2):

```
VM :-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/common/endorsed" 
    -Dcatalina.base="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0"  
    -Dcatalina.home="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0" 
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/temp" 
    -Xmx1024M
```