# Can't find Tomcat in Run/Debug Configurations - IntelliJ Ultimate 2016.2.4

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

[image]

As you can see from the image, when I'm trying to add Tomcat to my Run configurations, it doesn't show as an option but I have IntelliJ Ultimate, so I'm a little confused as to why it's not showing up. Am I missing a plugin?

Comment: You have to install the plugin. :))

Comment: Yeah haha, I remembered that when I installed IntelliJ, that I disabled the plugin on setup 

Comment: Can you guys tell which plugin do I need exactly?

Comment: If you go into Settings > Plugins, search for Tomcat and enable it, it should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ and Tomcat.. Howto..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041356/intellij-and-tomcat-howto)

Comment: This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047860/tomcat-in-intellij-idea-community-edition

Answer (score 10):

You should Install Tomcat and TomEE Integration plugin.

File –>> Settings –>> Type Plugin –>> Make sure Tomcat and TomEE Integration should be checked. Otherwise, you should install the plugin by clicking **Install JetBrains Plugin** button.

[image]

> Note: This plugin is only available in Ulimate edition

Comment: I can't find Tomcat and TomEE Integration

Comment: version: 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)
any suggestion?

Comment: CE version doesn't have this bundle plugin

Comment: when i am searching, i am unable to find this plugin

Comment: @AjayKhetan It's only available in idea ultimate edition. Updated the answer.