# Spring MVC project runs on terminal but getting error when run on Intellij

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I have a Spring MVC web application that should be deployed on Tomcat server. It gets deployed when I run it from terminal i.e., maven build and then copying and pasting the .war file in webapps folder of Tomcat. But when I build and run the same application in Intellij using Smart Tomcat plugin I get NullPoiinterException error. I do not how to debug it. I am new to Spring MVC. I have attaches the stacktract.txt file.

**stacktrace.txt**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'file' of com/intellij/openapi/module/ModuleUtilCore.findModuleForFile must not be null
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.ModuleUtilCore.$$$reportNull$$$0(ModuleUtilCore.java)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.ModuleUtilCore.findModuleForFile(ModuleUtilCore.java)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.conf.TomcatSettingsEditor$2.textChanged(TomcatSettingsEditor.java:150)
    at com.intellij.ui.DocumentAdapter.insertUpdate(DocumentAdapter.java:15)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:669)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1717)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.JBTextField.setText(JBTextField.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.TextFieldWithBrowseButton.setText(TextFieldWithBrowseButton.java:104)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.conf.TomcatSettingsEditor.resetEditorFrom(TomcatSettingsEditor.java:65)
    at com.poratu.idea.plugins.tomcat.conf.TomcatSettingsEditor.resetEditorFrom(TomcatSettingsEditor.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.lambda$resetFrom$0(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.bulkUpdate(SettingsEditor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.resetFrom(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditor$ConfigToSettingsWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditor.java:292)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditor$ConfigToSettingsWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditor.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.CompositeSettingsEditor.resetEditorFrom(CompositeSettingsEditor.java:52)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.java:98)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.resetEditorFrom(ConfigurationSettingsEditorWrapper.java:25)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.lambda$resetFrom$0(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.bulkUpdate(SettingsEditor.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditor.resetFrom(SettingsEditor.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.SettingsEditorConfigurable.reset(SettingsEditorConfigurable.java:41)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.SingleConfigurationConfigurable.reset(SingleConfigurationConfigurable.java:131)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.SingleConfigurationConfigurable.editSettings(SingleConfigurationConfigurable.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.getSafeUserObject(RunConfigurable.kt:352)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.access$getSafeUserObject(RunConfigurable.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$initTree$3.valueChanged(RunConfigurable.kt:239)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2927)
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3391)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:635)
    at com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.Tree$MySelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Tree.java:650)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1093)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:294)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPaths(JTree.java:1647)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionRows(JTree.java:1729)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionRow(JTree.java:1704)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.lambda$showAndSelect$10(TreeUtil.java:565)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.showAndSelect(TreeUtil.java:600)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.showRowCentered(TreeUtil.java:510)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.showRowCentered(TreeUtil.java:501)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.showRowCentred(TreeUtil.java:496)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.selectPath(TreeUtil.java:427)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.selectInTree(TreeUtil.java:909)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.tree.TreeUtil.selectInTree(TreeUtil.java:897)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.selectConfiguration(RunConfigurable.kt:307)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable.access$selectConfiguration(RunConfigurable.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.RunConfigurable$selectConfigurableOnShow$1.run(RunConfigurable.kt:283)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:668)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1681)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1630)
    at com.intellij.execution.actions.EditRunConfigurationsAction.actionPerformed(EditRunConfigurationsAction.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:275)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:287)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:283)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:277)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:522)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:35)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:544)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:664)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this by opening the IntelliJ settings -> Build, Execution, and Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle: From here I needed to update the selected gradle and SDK values. The ones from my project were incorrect, likely checked into version control that way. - https://github.com/raniejade/spek-idea-plugin/issues/30

Comment: I am using Maven. I followed the same steps for Maven. Even then I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in the third-party [Smart Tomcat](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9492-smart-tomcat) plug-in, you should [report it here](https://github.com/zengkid/SmartTomcat/issues).

[Disabling](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) the plug-in should help. Use the built-in Tomcat integration in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Community edition. How can I make it run in that?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA CE doesn't have Tomcat integration. If you have a problem with the Smart Tomcat plug-in, you should report it to the vendor.

Comment: Ok. If I should make it work in CE then should I manually deploy the .war file in the webapps folder of tomcat?

Comment: All the available options were already listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266010/104891).

Comment: I am getting an error even after running the application in Eclipse. I cannot use Jetty because the requirement specifies to use Tomcat.

Comment: You can still use Gradle or Maven to deploy and run your app on Tomcat.

Comment: Ok. I do not know how to do it yet. I will check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188979/discussion-between-laxman-and-crazycoder).