# Glassfish 5 (Payara Server) in Intellij Idea 2020 Community Edition

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, payara, glassfish-5

I'm following a tutorial with `Payara Server 5.2020.4` and `IntelliJ Version: 2020.2.1.`

The tutor is using `IntelliJ` **`Ultimate`**, and I have only `IntelliJ` **`Community`**.

I know about of the existence of `Netbeans` / `Eclipse` are already enable for that, and I was using them.

But, I have still the doubt and I would like to solve it.

**Is it possible via `pom.xml` add support for `Glassfish/Payara` server like this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767474/811293) for Tomcat?**

And **How to do it?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to integrate Payara Server with any IDE using maven.

This is possible using the general Cargo maven plugin, which supports many application servers, including Payara Server. You can see how to do it in Payara blog here:

https://blog.payara.fish/deploying-to-payara-server-using-the-maven-cargo-plugin

and documentation of Payara Server support in Cargo plugin here:

https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.4/documentation/user-guides/using-the-maven-cargo-plugin.html