# idea community one tomcat instance run multiple webapps

Tags: intellij-idea

in idea community 2020.2, i created one project with two modules(maven war package) - `demo1` and `demo2`.

i installed `smart tomcat`.

can i run these two webapps in one tomcat instance(such that they are in the same port) in idea?(**not** start tomcat out of idea munally then deploys all webapps to outer tomcat)

just like in eclipse, we can create a server and add multiple webapps to it and start all webapps at one time with same port.

could we do that in idea community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in Community edition.

[Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition and it allows multiple applications run and deploy on the same Tomcat instance. See also this answer: [Tomcat in Intellij Idea Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047860/tomcat-in-intellij-idea-community-edition).

Answer (score 0):

Polaris Tomcat Server plugin is now available in Intellij Idea Community Edition. It supports running multiple web apps.